# binding object member List of string in a dataList

Tags: asp.net, listview, repeater, datalist

I have the following Class:

```
public class MinistryModel
    {
        public string MinistryName { get; set; }
        public string MinistryMission { get; set; }
        public string MinistryVision { get; set; }
        public string MinistrySpecialities { get; set; }
        public string MinistryUrl { get; set; }
        public List<string> MinistryServices { get; set; }

    }
```

and i want to bind this element to a data list in asp.net, for all the attributes i can do  <%#Eval("PropertName") %> but when i want to use each string of MinistryServices apart, what can i do ?

If i do  <%#Eval("MinistryServices") %> i will get all of the strings, wheras i want to have them separated,

ie : i want to do something like this

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataListDescriptions" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <div>DataBinder info for Ministry# Description</div>
        <ul id="tab1">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li class="active">
            <div class="desc-title">specialities</div>
            <p class="gray"><%#Eval("MinistrySpecialities") %></p>
            <div class="desc-title center golden">services</div>
            <div class="center">
                <a class="black" href="<%#Eval("MinistryUrl") %>">
                    <%#Eval("MinistryUrl") %>
                </a>
            </div>
            <asp:DataList ID="MinistryServiesData" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <ul id="tabs11" class="ministry-services black">
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li class="">
                        <span class="golden arabic-num"></span>
                        ((HOW CAN I PARSE THIS LIST OF STRING HERE ??)
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </ul>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: You could use a nested web-control(repeater, gridview,datalist) and use that list as datasource. The quick and dirty version, use a `Label` and:           `Text='<%# string.Join("<br>", ((List<string>)Eval("MinistryServices"))) %>'`

Comment: "and use that list as datasource"  every list of services depends on Ministry name (means every minister have its services) so i can't get the specific list from code behind to bind it to the web-control (because it depends on the changing name) (this can't be done from behind code)

Comment: is there any way i can do this from asp ? i just want to put each one inside the li ...

Comment: Why can't this be done from codebehind (`ItemDataBound`)? Every item has a `DataItem` property which is the `MinistryModel`.

Comment: how can i from code behind  get the actual ministry name , and then bind its services to the web-control (repeater for example) the rest can be done (getting the services) ...?

Comment: In the way i've already mentioned, use `ItemDataBound` which is called for every item in the `DataList` and cast `e.Item.DataItem` to `MinistryModel`. Then you have all you need. Use `e.Item.FindControl("ControlID")` to get the reference to all controls you need(f.e. the nested databound web-control).